# Change the menu's color after being pressed

Tags: android, menu, colors

So I can change the color of a options menu item no problem. However, I would like to change the color that menu items flash when pressed from green to orange. Everywhere I look has nothing on this. Please help.

Comment: Please elaborate, what menu are you talking about?

Comment: I meant the options menu, sorry that wasn't clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to change the color of the menu item while having your finger pressed down on the button, before actually releasing it, you likely want to look into an onKeyDown() event handler. In that handler, I would change the color of the menu item, and then in the onKeyUp() handler, change the color back.

There might be a more elegant way of handling this, however. You can visit the Android SDK [UI Event Handlers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html) page for more information.